# How to create an array of objects with one of the properties being an array from a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I got this array:

```
[
name1, 
email1@name1.com,
email2@name1.com,
email3@name1.com,
name2,
email1@name2.com,
name3,
name4,
email1@name4.com,
email2@name4.com,
email3@name4.com,
email4@name4.com,
email5@name4.com,
]
```

From that array I need to parse it and create an array like the following:

```
[
{ dlName: < element without @ > , members: [<elements with @ >]}, 
{ dlName: < element without @ > , members: [<elements with @ >]}, 
{ dlName: < element without @ > , members: [<elements with @ >]}
]
```

example:

```
[
  HR,
  someonefks@name.com,
  fjkdafaldksjh@name.com,
  sfafafads@name.com,
  cyber,
  fakdjfnakj@name.com,
  fdsfasfasds@name.com,
  accessibility,
  accounting,
   dasaasas@name.com,
   klhdaflkaa@name.com
]
```

output:

```
[
{ dlName: HR , members: [someonefks@name.com,fjkdafaldksjh@name.com,sfafafads@name.com,]}, 
{ dlName: cyber , members:[fakdjfnakj@name.com,fdsfasfasds@name.com,]}, 
{ dlName: accesibility , members: []},
{ dlName: accounting , members: [dasaasas@name.com,klhdaflkaa@name.com]}
]
```

How can I get this output, everything I tried does not work for me needs.

Thanks in advance

Comment: a bit unclear can you give the expected output based on the input provided

Comment: I just update it with examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the array by having a look to the strings.

If you got an `'@'` add the string to the last object to `members`, otherose add a new object to the result set.

```js
const
    data = ['name1', 'email1@name1.com', 'email2@name1.com', 'email3@name1.com', 'name2', 'email1@name2.com', 'name3', 'name4', 'email1@name4.com', 'email2@name4.com', 'email3@name4.com', 'email4@name4.com', 'email5@name4.com'],
    result = data.reduce((r, v) => {
        if (v.includes('@')) r[r.length - 1].members.push(v);
        else r.push(({ dlName: v, members: [] }));
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this is almost perfect, I forgot to mention there are some undefined values in there too and it changes a bit the output. I will try to tinkle with your solution. I will mark it as accepted as it solves the problem I asked for. Thanks!